# Issue dereferencing pointers

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between those two programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
int* ptr;
*ptr = 600;

printf("ptr = %d\n", *ptr );
return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
int* ptr = (int*) 600;

printf("ptr = %d\n", *ptr );
return 0;
}
```

Why on the first one I receive `ptr = 600`, while on the second, I receive an error saying that the program has stopped working?

Comment: Undefined behavior is like a box of chocolates; you never know what you're going to get.

Comment: @WhozCraig or, better, box of live spiders. :P

Answer (score 1):

Both your programs invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- The first one, writing to an unitialized pointer.
- The second one, reading from a *possibly* invalid memory location. FWIW, conversion of an `int` to a pointer type is also implementation-defined behaviour.

Solution:

Allocate *proper* memory to `ptr` before you dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between those two programs:

First piece :

```
int* ptr; // Uninitialized pointer
*ptr = 600; // Dereferencing causes undefined behaviour
```

Second  piece :

```
int* ptr = (int*) 600; //600 - A memory location which you may not have access to.
printf("ptr = %d\n", *ptr ); // Dereferencing causes undefined behaviour
```

> Conclusion

There is no difference. Both will crash sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

### Both examples fail in their own way

In the first example, you are writing `600` to wherever `ptr` points, which is undefined because the pointer was never assigned to anything.  It may *seem* to work because it is writing `600` *somewhere* then reading the value back.  You just got lucky that accessing this *somewhere* didn't cause a segmentation fault.

In the second example, you are explicitly assigning the *address* `600` to the variable `ptr`.  This is a rather low value for a memory address, which is almost certainly not somewhere in memory you should be trying to read from.  When you dereference it (the line with the `printf`), your program "stopped working" because it attempted to read memory from somewhere it shouldn't.

In short, neither one works.  But the way in which the first one fails is a bit more deceptive.

---

### A bit on pointers

Memory is a strange and wonderful thing in that fundamentally everything is just bytes of binary data.  When reading anything from memory, a compiler needs some notion of:

- where to start reading
- how much to read
- how to interpret it

The line from your second example `int *ptr = (int *)600` declares the variable `ptr` as a pointer to an `int`.  The pointer `ptr` allows you to read from arbitrary places in memory when dereferencing it (with `*ptr`). Notice how the three above requirements are specified.  The value of `ptr` is where to start reading.  The other two requirements are given by its type `int *`, which includes the type of the thing it points to: read `sizeof(int)` bytes and interpret what is read as a signed integer `int`.

("How to interpret it" is a bit optional.  A `void *` for example specifies "where to start reading", but explicitly gives no notion of how to interpret what is there, leaving it only as bytes of binary data.  Any interface that uses a `void *` likely has some other mechanism for specifying "how much to read", such as another parameter of type `size_t`.)

The initialization `(int *)600` contains a type cast.  This *forces* the compiler to think of `600` as the memory address where an `int` resides, making it a value compatible to assign to `int *ptr`.  Hard-coding an address like this is almost certainly asking for trouble, unless you really know what you're doing (have a memory map for the machine you're writing for, etc.) and have a good reason to do so (e.g. memory-mapped I/O, etc.).  In short, you are not giving a useful address.

As an analogy, imagine that you need to buy something, and know of a place that sells it.  You send your friend out to buy it for you.  But your friend is not very bright.  He will do exactly as you tell him, but you must give short and simple instructions.  You tell him to go to a specific address and buy four of whatever they sell.  What could possibly go wrong?  In your case, you got your friend arrested for trespassing.  These instructions depend entirely on whether or not you provide a correct address.  In the second example, he was not allowed to go to address 600, and was stopped trying to get there.

It also depends on whether or not the store you are thinking of even exists.  In both of your examples, `ptr` has a meaningless value.  To follow the analogy with your first example, you are not providing any address at all.  Your friend instead goes to the last place he was thinking of, gives something (the number 600) to whomever is there, then takes it back.  If it worked, it was only because you got lucky about where he went and the person he encountered was cooperative.

---

### Pointers are more useful when they point to things

The way to "fix" your code is to make your pointers actually point to something meaningful.  In both examples, you don't actually have a variable of type `int` that is yours to use anywhere in memory.  You could allocate an `int` as a local variable (on the stack) and have `ptr` point to it with something like:

```
int x;          // now x is an int that actually exists
int *ptr = &x;  // initialize ptr to point to x
```

Then any assignment to `*ptr` would write to `x`, for example:

```
*ptr = 600;  // now x == 600
```

The more useful thing to do with pointers is to use dynamically allocated heap memory, as in:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
if ( ptr != NULL ) {
    *ptr = 600;
}
```

This allocates an `int` in heap memory, makes `ptr` point to it, then (if it was successfully allocated) writes `600` to it.  A heap allocation like this call to `malloc()` is what appears to be missing from your first example.

Comment: So when I say int* ptr = (int*) 600, I am saying that there is an int in the address 600?

Comment: `int *ptr = (int *)600` assigns the address 600 (a meaningless address) to `ptr`.  Since `ptr` is declared as a pointer to an `int`, when you later dereference it with `*ptr`, the program tries to read an `int` (of size `sizeof(int)`) from this address. You are more or less _implying_ that there is an `int` at address 600. You never actually have an `int`. What is actually at address 600 is not yours anyway, so your program is terminated by the system when you try to read from it.